# To write the text message using javascript in current page

Tags: javascript

In the below code i have a textbox i have to validate the textbox. if it is success it should write success .But in mycase it print success in next page but i want to display in current page.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

        var iReturn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (!txtInput.match(re)) {
                iReturn = iReturn + 1;
            }
        }

        if (iReturn > 0) {
           // alert("Failed...");
            document.write("Failed...");
        }
        else {
           // alert("Success...");
            document.write("Success...");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please try to provide a working demonstration of the problem and all the relevant source code.

Comment: `document.write` _changes_ the page content (something about the document closing.. nvm that). Instead, look into selecting elements (with `getElementById`) and changing their `.textContent`.

Comment: When i write  document.write("Success..."); it is printing in another page